# Adding swap partition with LVM

Tags: rhel, lvm, swap

I have a simple question. 
I have a virtual machine already installed with RHEL7 and I have to add the swap partition to the system. I haven't enough free space on the PV so I have to add a new disk. What is the best way to add this swap space?
Thank you

Comment: To get better answers you might want to also specify which VM technology you are using, eg. VirtualBox?  Also I'm assuming that when you say you have no free space you mean no free allocatable space within the VM.  In which case create a new small virtual disk and add it to the VM to be configured as swap.

Comment: Hi John, the VM technology is VMware and yes, I have not free space both in the physical volume and in the volume group. My worry is: after adding a new vmdk and having defined it as a physical volume with "pvcreate newpartition", can I extend the volume group while LVM is using the volume group?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use `vgextend`.

Comment: So, since I'll convert the logical volume as swap (mkswap /dev/vg/lvswap) I don't need to format it as a swap partition in the fdisk command, right?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

1. add a virtual disk via VMware Player
2. format it as filesystem type 0x82 (swap)
3. initialize the swap via `mkswap`
4. enable the swap via `swapon`

Alternatively, you can use a swap file instead of a swap partition: create a 1 Gb (or whatever size is needed) swap file via `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1024000`, then proceed with steps 3 and 4.